# need to get postthumnails from a post whithin a category custom post type

Tags: taxonomy

i try to get postthumnail from a  a post whithin category i have just create.
here is my code

```
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
        <?php if ( has_post_thumbnail()) { ?>
<?php } ?> 
<?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>
    <?php // on va chercher les projets  ?>  
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'post_type'      => "projet",
        'showposts'      => 6,
    );    
    // fonction qui va créer une requete et chercher les données
    query_posts( $args );     
    ?>
    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?> 
<section>                  
 <a class="link_fx pushup" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
  <figure > 

<?php 

if (class_exists('MultiPostThumbnails')) : 
MultiPostThumbnails::the_post_thumbnail(get_post_type(), 'secondary-image-projet',);
endif;?>

    <figcaption>
    <p class="description_item"> <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
      </p>
       </figcaption>
    </figure>
  </a>
  <!---End projets-->
  </section>


    <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

    <?php wp_reset_query(); //pour reinitialiser la boucle par défault ?>
```

what do i have to add to get only one category of "projet" ?
If anyone could help me ?

Comment: Categories don't have thumbnails. Are you trying to get the thumbnail from a post within a category?

Comment: You'right , i am trying to get thepostthumnail from a post in a category i juste created and named categoriesprojets

Comment: [**Dont. Use. `query_posts()`**](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/query_posts/#more-information), create a new WP_Query()

Answer (score 0):

$args = 
    array( 
    'post_type' => ‘Projet’, 
    ’ma_taxonomy' => 'construction' 
)

query_posts($args)